# Exception: Invalid attempt to Read when reader is closed

Tags: c#, mysql

I am trying to update my database while reading data from it, but the reader gets closed and it throws the exception that it can''t read wen reader is closed. Is the `update.ExecuteNonQuery()` closing the reader method?

If i get rid of lines`con.Close();` `con.Open();` i get `There is already an open DataReader associated with this Connection which must be closed first.`

So how can i update my database records while keep the reading opened?

```
{
    public class MySqlReadUpdate
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Notes { get; set; }
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        List<MySqlReadUpdate> dbData = new List<MySqlReadUpdate>();

        var config = "server=localhost;user id=root; database=restaurants; pooling=false;SslMode=none;Pooling=True";
        MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(config);

        MySqlDataReader reader = null;
        string query = "SELECT id, notes FROM customers";

        MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(query, con);
        con.Open();
        reader = command.ExecuteReader();

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            MySqlReadUpdate newMySqlReadUpdate = new MySqlReadUpdate();

            newMySqlReadUpdate.Id = (int)reader["id"];
            newMySqlReadUpdate.Notes = (string)reader["notes"];
            string note = newMySqlReadUpdate.Notes;
            var notesplit = note.Split(' ', '\n')[1];
            dbData.Add(newMySqlReadUpdate);
            Console.WriteLine(newMySqlReadUpdate.Id);
            Console.WriteLine(newMySqlReadUpdate.Notes);
            Console.WriteLine(note);
            Console.WriteLine(notesplit);
            con.Close();
            con.Open();

            string query2 = "UPDATE customers SET notes='" + notesplit + "' WHERE id='" + newMySqlReadUpdate.Id + "';";
            MySqlCommand update = new MySqlCommand(query2, con);
            update.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        con.Close();

        Console.WriteLine("Finished!");
        Console.Read();

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you get exception at `update.ExecuteNonQuery();` ?

Comment: I get an exception at `while (reader.Read())`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot close a connection like you are, because the data reader depends on it. Once you call `con.Close` you break it. That's why you see an exception the next time it gets to `reader.Read()`.

What you want is to add `MultipleActiveResultSets=True` in the configuration string; however, as we discussed in the comments it's apparently still not supported in MySQL. Therefore, the answer is two connection instances.

```
 List<MySqlReadUpdate> dbData = new List<MySqlReadUpdate>();

 var config = "server=localhost;user id=root;database=restaurants;pooling=false;SslMode=none";
 MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(config);
 MySqlConnection cmdCon = new MySqlConnection(config);

 MySqlDataReader reader = null;
 string query = "SELECT id, notes FROM customers";

 MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(query, con);
 con.Open();
 cmdCon.Open();
 reader = command.ExecuteReader();

 while (reader.Read())
 {
     MySqlReadUpdate newMySqlReadUpdate = new MySqlReadUpdate();

     newMySqlReadUpdate.Id = (int)reader["id"];
     newMySqlReadUpdate.Notes = (string)reader["notes"];
     string note = newMySqlReadUpdate.Notes;
     var notesplit = note.Split(' ', '\n')[1];
     dbData.Add(newMySqlReadUpdate);
     Console.WriteLine(newMySqlReadUpdate.Id);
     Console.WriteLine(newMySqlReadUpdate.Notes);
     Console.WriteLine(note);
     Console.WriteLine(notesplit);

     string query2 = "UPDATE customers SET notes='" + notesplit + "' WHERE id='" + newMySqlReadUpdate.Id + "';";
     MySqlCommand update = new MySqlCommand(query2, cmdCon);
     update.ExecuteNonQuery();
 }
 con.Close();
 cmdCon.Close();

 Console.WriteLine("Finished!");
 Console.Read();
```

I would recommend that you also modify your code to use `using` statements or wrap things in try-finally blocks.

Comment: I have tried it but MySQL doesn't support MultipleActiveResultSets as a parameter. It only work for SQL

Comment: I thought they added it some time ago. Surprising that after all these years support hasn't been added. So assuming that is true, then two connection instances are necessary. (And I believe pooling will need to be off. Your current connection string sets it twice.)

Comment: Yes, but reader gets closed and it stops reading database table and i don't understand why it gets closed